# CSV Template for Data Import

Tags: sql-server, node.js, csv, t-sql

I need to import data into database using a CSV file and here is my table structure.

[image: vehicle_db]

One vehicle can have multiple attachments(images,pdf,doc,etc..)

This is my current CSV template.

```
"vehicleMake", "vehicleModel", "vehicleRego", "attachmentName" 
"Nissan",      "Qashqai",      "ASY504",      "abc.pdf"
"Hyundai",     "Lantra",       "OCR491",      "xyz.png"
"HONDA",       "CIVIC",        "WXO839",      "qwe.txt"
```

I got stuck when there is more than one attachment for a vehicle.

What is the best practice to add multiple `attachmentName`s in CSV?

Comma separated attachment names like this, `"123.pdf, xyz.jpeg, test.png"` or is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have, is that you are trying to map a 1:n structure to a flat file format. 
I usually get this kind of data as multiple rows eg:

```
"HONDA",       "CIVIC",        "WXO839",      "123.txt"
"HONDA",       "CIVIC",        "WXO839",      "xyz.txt"
"HONDA",       "CIVIC",        "WXO839",      "test.txt"
```

you´ll then have to transform that upon import. 
Over your approach, this one has no limitations in the number of attachments that can be added. The disadvantage is that it takes more space trough redundancy.

This is the opposite of normalization in a Entity-relationship model.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll try this.

Answer (score 0):

Split CSV files in two (import table vehicle attachment seperately) and add VehicleID in Vehicle_attachment to link to Vehicle table.
You may need to export Vehicle table, to use ID's generated there.